# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment when trying to run Java

Tags: java

I have strange error when I am trying to run java on my Raspberry pi 3. It also shows when I am trying to do any other java shell command as java -version. Reboot didn't help. I tried reinstalling java but it didn't help.
Command: `sudo java -jar NodeJSAutoRun.jar` 
Error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x769d5130, pid=5043, tid=5044
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.8+10) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.8+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing, serial gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x788130]
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pi/Programs/hs_err_pid5043.log
#
#
Aborted
```

Edit:
Content of the error report file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x769d5130, pid=5043, tid=5044
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.8+10) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.8+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing, serial gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x788130]
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: NodeJSAutoRun.jar

Host: rev 4 (v7l), 4 cores, 926M, Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Time: Wed Sep 16 16:49:22 2020 CEST elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x75f0e800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=5044, stack(0x76007000,0x76057000)]

Stack: [0x76007000,0x76057000],  sp=0x76055be8,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x788130]
V  [libjvm.so+0x705014]
V  [libjvm.so+0x705074]
V  [libjvm.so+0x4d7278]
V  [libjvm.so+0x929ce0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x580c84]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x78


siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000154

Registers:
  r0  = 0x000000f8
  r1  = 0x00000000
  r2  = 0x007b47d0
  r3  = 0x00000000
  r4  = 0x76055c24
  r5  = 0x75f104e8
  r6  = 0x00000000
  r7  = 0x00000000
  r8  = 0x76cd0904
  r9  = 0x76055dbf
  r10 = 0x75f0e580
  fp  = 0x76055c0c
  r12 = 0x76cd0c90
  sp  = 0x76055be8
  lr  = 0x76f2e300
  pc  = 0x769d5130
  cpsr = 0x00000010

Top of Stack: (sp=0x76055be8)
0x76055be8:   75f00010 76055c24 75f104e8 00000000
0x76055bf8:   00000000 76cd0904 76055dbf 75f0e580
0x76055c08:   76055c44 76952014 00000000 00000000
0x76055c18:   75f0e800 76c5d368 75f0e800 75f0e800
0x76055c28:   76055c54 76cd0904 76055c54 76055ca8
0x76055c38:   75f0e800 76055ce8 76055c4c 76952074
0x76055c48:   76055c84 76724278 76055c84 75f0e800
0x76055c58:   75f0f0c0 75f0f0e0 75f0f0e8 75f0f1d4 

Instructions: (pc=0x769d5130)
0x769d5030:   e2841030 ebf07128 e1a00005 e284104c
0x769d5040:   ebf07165 e1a10005 e2841068 ebf07162
0x769d5050:   e1a00005 e2841084 ebf0715f e1a00005
0x769d5060:   e28510a0 ebf0715c e1a08105 e28410bc
0x769d5070:   ebf07159 e1a02005 f68410d8 ebf0715e
0x769d5080:   e1a00004 e8b98870 0025bd42 002f9dec
0x769d5090:   002fba90 00003df4 002877d4 0027a0a3
0x769d50a0:   00245e6c 00282664 00287830 00287870
0x769d50b0:   00287864 002c78c0 00287868 00287930
0x769d50c0:   00255b58 4028fa0c 01287964 0028796e
0x769d50d0:   002577f4 000007b4 00287848 04287840
0x769d50e0:   002832f4 00282d78 e2510020 e52db804
0x769d50f0:   e28db000 0a000082 e28bd000 e49db014
0x769d5100:   eaffff0e e28bd000 e49db004 e12fff1e
0x769d5110:   e59f00b0 e92d4ff8 a08f0000 e28db024
0x769d5120:   ebe43159 e3a01000 e5903100 e3a000f8
0x769d5130:   e5934154 e5946008 e594900c e5148090
0x769d5140:   e594a016 eb037110 e2505000 01a47005
0x769d5150:   4a00000c e3a02000 e1a01006 ebffff33
0x769d5160:   e285000c ebf0733f e5953000 e5933010
0x769d5170:   e1a07004 e1a00005 e12fff33 e5d53008
0x769d5180:   e3530000 1a00000c e5973000 e3530000
0x769d5190:   0a000004 e1a00004 e0a0120a e3e6ca9b
0x769d51a0:   e1a00006 ebe6c623 e584e008 e584900c
0x769d51b0:   e5848010 e1a00007 e8bd8ffc e3a00005
0x769d51c0:   ebc6c016 eaffffef 0030153c e92d4ff0
0x769d51d0:   e28db080 e59f5264 e24bd79f e34ddfa1
0x769d51e0:   e1a08021 e180a020 e50922a4 e1a03005
0x769d51f0:   e24b1f4b e3a02022 e0874004 e5832000
0x769d5200:   e5836004 e5832008 e5832004 e2833010
0x769d5210:   e1510003 1afffff8 e24b9f69 e1a00009
0x769d5220:   e24b107c f3a06000 e3a07200 e50b212c 



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x007b4630, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x76b742ac]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (1 events):
Event: 0.007 Protecting memory [0x76007000,0x7600a000] with protection modes 0


Dynamic libraries:
00010000-00011000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 155172     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java
00020000-00021000 r--p 00000000 b3:07 155172     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java
00021000-00022000 rw-p 00001000 b3:07 155172     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java
007ac000-007cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
75cfb000-75d04000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167723     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.28.so
75d04000-75d14000 ---p 00009000 b3:07 167723     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.28.so
75d14000-75d15000 r--p 00009000 b3:07 167723     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.28.so
75d15000-75d16000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:07 167723     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnss_files-2.28.so
75d16000-75d1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
75d33000-75e9f000 r--s 00000000 b3:07 155249     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/modules
75e9f000-75ebd000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 155227     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjava.so
75ebd000-75ecc000 ---p 0001e000 b3:07 155227     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjava.so
75ecc000-75ecd000 r--p 0001d000 b3:07 155227     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjava.so
75ecd000-75ece000 rw-p 0001e000 b3:07 155227     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjava.so
75ece000-75ed8000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 155247     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libverify.so
75ed8000-75ee7000 ---p 0000a000 b3:07 155247     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libverify.so
75ee7000-75ee8000 r--p 00009000 b3:07 155247     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libverify.so
75ee8000-75ee9000 rw-p 0000a000 b3:07 155247     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libverify.so
75ee9000-75eef000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167626     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.28.so
75eef000-75efe000 ---p 00006000 b3:07 167626     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.28.so
75efe000-75eff000 r--p 00005000 b3:07 167626     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.28.so
75eff000-75f00000 rw-p 00006000 b3:07 167626     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt-2.28.so
75f00000-75f21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
75f21000-76000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
76007000-7600a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7600a000-76057000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
76057000-76073000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167707     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
76073000-76082000 ---p 0001c000 b3:07 167707     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
76082000-76083000 r--p 0001b000 b3:07 167707     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
76083000-76084000 rw-p 0001c000 b3:07 167707     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1
76084000-760f5000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167673     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.28.so
760f5000-76104000 ---p 00071000 b3:07 167673     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.28.so
76104000-76105000 r--p 00070000 b3:07 167673     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.28.so
76105000-76106000 rw-p 00071000 b3:07 167673     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm-2.28.so
76106000-76234000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 542103     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
76234000-76244000 ---p 0012e000 b3:07 542103     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
76244000-76249000 r--p 0012e000 b3:07 542103     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
76249000-7624b000 rw-p 00133000 b3:07 542103     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
7624b000-7624d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7624d000-76c87000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 396626     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/server/libjvm.so
76c87000-76c96000 ---p 00a3a000 b3:07 396626     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/server/libjvm.so
76c96000-76cd7000 r--p 00a39000 b3:07 396626     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/server/libjvm.so
76cd7000-76cf0000 rw-p 00a7a000 b3:07 396626     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/server/libjvm.so
76cf0000-76d1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
76d1b000-76e53000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167746     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
76e53000-76e63000 ---p 00138000 b3:07 167746     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
76e63000-76e65000 r--p 00138000 b3:07 167746     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
76e65000-76e66000 rw-p 0013a000 b3:07 167746     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
76e66000-76e69000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
76e69000-76e6b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167647     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.28.so
76e6b000-76e7a000 ---p 00002000 b3:07 167647     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.28.so
76e7a000-76e7b000 r--p 00001000 b3:07 167647     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.28.so
76e7b000-76e7c000 rw-p 00002000 b3:07 167647     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl-2.28.so
76e7c000-76e89000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 155211     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/jli/libjli.so
76e89000-76e98000 ---p 0000d000 b3:07 155211     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/jli/libjli.so
76e98000-76e99000 r--p 0000c000 b3:07 155211     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/jli/libjli.so
76e99000-76e9a000 rw-p 0000d000 b3:07 155211     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/jli/libjli.so
76e9a000-76eb1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167607     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
76eb1000-76ec0000 ---p 00017000 b3:07 167607     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
76ec0000-76ec1000 r--p 00016000 b3:07 167607     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
76ec1000-76ec2000 rw-p 00017000 b3:07 167607     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
76ec2000-76ec4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
76ec4000-76ede000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167652     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.11
76ede000-76eed000 ---p 0001a000 b3:07 167652     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.11
76eed000-76eee000 r--p 00019000 b3:07 167652     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.11
76eee000-76eef000 rw-p 0001a000 b3:07 167652     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1.2.11
76ef1000-76ef5000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 155231     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjimage.so
76ef5000-76f04000 ---p 00004000 b3:07 155231     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjimage.so
76f04000-76f05000 r--p 00003000 b3:07 155231     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjimage.so
76f05000-76f06000 rw-p 00004000 b3:07 155231     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/libjimage.so
76f06000-76f0a000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 543336     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
76f0a000-76f19000 ---p 00004000 b3:07 543336     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
76f19000-76f1a000 r--p 00003000 b3:07 543336     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
76f1a000-76f1b000 rw-p 00004000 b3:07 543336     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
76f1b000-76f3b000 r-xp 00000000 b3:07 167767     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
76f3e000-76f46000 rw-s 00000000 b3:07 540587     /tmp/hsperfdata_root/5043
76f46000-76f47000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
76f47000-76f4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
76f4b000-76f4c000 r--p 00020000 b3:07 167767     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
76f4c000-76f4d000 rw-p 00021000 b3:07 167767     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
7ee64000-7ee85000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
7efdd000-7efde000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
7efde000-7efdf000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
7efdf000-7efe0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]


VM Arguments:
java_command: NodeJSAutoRun.jar
java_class_path (initial): NodeJSAutoRun.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 15184512                                  {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 242952192                                 {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseSerialGC                              = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x99824c], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x99824c], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x99824c], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x7b8058], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x7b8058], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x99824c], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x7b7ef0], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
uname:Linux 5.4.51-v7+ #1327 SMP Thu Jul 23 10:58:46 BST 2020 armv7l
OS uptime: 0 days 0:44 hours
libc:glibc 2.28 NPTL 2.28 
rlimit (soft/hard): STACK 8192k/infinity , CORE 0k/infinity , NPROC 6894/6894 , NOFILE 1048576/1048576 , AS infinity/infinity , CPU infinity/infinity , DATA infinity/infinity , FSIZE infinity/infinity , MEMLOCK infinity/infinity
load average:0.09 0.07 0.06

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:         949032 kB
MemFree:          522500 kB
MemAvailable:     754100 kB
Buffers:           37744 kB
Cached:           238664 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           226140 kB
Inactive:         154432 kB
Active(anon):     104468 kB
Inactive(anon):     6648 kB
Active(file):     121672 kB
Inactive(file):   147784 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:        102396 kB
SwapFree:         102396 kB
Dirty:                32 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        104256 kB
Mapped:            85792 kB
Shmem:              6956 kB
KReclaimable:      14396 kB
Slab:              28444 kB
SReclaimable:      14396 kB
SUnreclaim:        14048 kB
KernelStack:        1880 kB
PageTables:         3688 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      576912 kB
Committed_AS:    1437236 kB
VmallocTotal:    1114112 kB
VmallocUsed:        3552 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              416 kB
CmaTotal:          65536 kB
CmaFree:           63636 kB

/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled:
  <Not Available>

/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag (defrag/compaction efforts parameter):
  <Not Available>


/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max (system-wide limit on the number of threads):
13788


/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count (maximum number of memory map areas a process may have):
65530


/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max (system-wide limit on number of process identifiers):
32768



/etc/ld.so.preload:
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so

Steal ticks since vm start: 0
Steal ticks percentage since vm start:  0.000

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) 

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 51.20
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 51.20
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 51.20
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 51.20
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a02082
Serial      : 00000000d72f503f
Model       : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2

Memory: 4k page, physical 949032k(522500k free), swap 102396k(102396k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.8+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1) for linux- JRE (11.0.8+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1), built on Jul 23 2020 14:58:04 by "unknown" with gcc 8.3.0

END.
```

Can you help me?
**Edit 2:** I solved it by reinstalling whole Raspberry pi, so I can't tell you if your answer worked.

Comment: Is there anything helpful in the error report file?  `An error report file with more information is saved as: /home/pi/Programs/hs_err_pid5043.log`

Comment: @Paul, I edited it.

Comment: What happens when you try `java -version`? How did you install java?

Comment: @matt, the java was installed on the rpi from first boot. And when I do java -version, it shows also this error, so it is probably corupted java.

Comment: It sounds like it. I *think* I downloaded adoptopenjdk arm32 version and it worked on my raspberry pi.(It is put away in a box right now :( so I cannot verify that is true.) Have you updated your OS? Maybe have it re-install java, as an actual file is corrupt.

Comment: It looks like either the java installation is corrupt or a non-suitable java version was installed. Maybe you should try to re-install java?

Comment: @Abra I tried to reinstall java, but when I was removing it, there was error, that java is not installed and when I was installing it, there was also some error.

Comment: ok, so i tried to reinstall java, but nothing.